# EF Core 2.1 check if pair of properties exist in table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Im try to refactor this method to take list of items:

```
public async Task<bool> IfExist(string id1, string id2)
{
    return await DbSet.AnyAsync(x => x.Id1 == id1 && x.Id2 == id2 &&);
}
```

That method works perfectly and produce `SQL` that looks like this:

```
Command: SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM "SomeTable" AS x
        WHERE ((x."Id1" = @__id1) AND (x."Id2" = @__id2))
    THEN TRUE::bool ELSE FALSE::bool
END
-- Parameters:
@__id1: value
@__id2: value
```

But now, i want to write `IfExist` method that takes lists of ids and checking pairs of `id1` and `id2`. I wrote something like this:

```
public async Task<bool> IfExist(IEnumerable<string> ids1, IEnumerable<string> ids2)
{
    var ids = ids1.Zip(ids2, (id1, id2) => new { id1, id2 });

    return await DbSet.AnyAsync(x => ids.Contains(new { id1 = x.Id1, id2 = x.Id2 }));
}
```

But its just execute `SELECT * FROM ...` on my database so basiclly this query is executed in memory, not in database. EF Core 2.1 cant produce `SQL` code from that `LINQ` query.

My question is, how to write query that check if any pair of two properties exist in whole table using EF Core 2.1 and LINQ?

Edint when i try to contains existing of `Tuple<string, string>` its still not work correctly and executed `SQL` looks like this:

```
Command: SELECT x."Id1", x."Id2"
FROM "SomeTable" AS x
```

So it means that my query download whole table from DB and make a linq query in memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I needed to build custom expression with this case. I needed to check two ids, then set `OR` in `SQL` and then check second pair of ids, then set `OR` and so on.

After while i developed this solution that looks it works:

```
// main func...
{
    var ids = ids1.Zip(ids2, (id1, id2) => (Id1: id1, Id2: id2));

    var query = DbSet.AsQueryable();
    var filter = MakeExpression(ids);
    query = query.Where(filter);

    return await query.AnyAsync();

}

private Expression<Func<Data, bool>> MakeExpression(
    IEnumerable<(string id1, string id2)> ids
    )
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Data), "x");
    var memberId1 = Expression.Property(parameter, nameof(Data.Id1));
    var memberId2 = Expression.Property(parameter, nameof(Data.Id2));

    var expression = Expression.NotEqual(Expression.Constant(1), Expression.Constant(1));
    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        var idsAnd = Expression.AndAlso(
            Expression.Equal(memberId1, Expression.Constant(id.id1)),
            Expression.Equal(memberId2, Expression.Constant(id.id2)));

        expression = Expression.Or(expression, idsAnd);
     }

     var lambda = (Expression<Func<Data, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(expression, parameter);

     return lambda;
}
```

Comment: It seems good too, but need to check its performance due to lots of `WHERE` clauses

Comment: I belive that we can write it better using `Expressions`, but im newbie in EF

Answer (score 1):

EF Core doesn't have any option to natively support that behaviour. One solution would be something like this:

```
return await DbSet.Where(x => ids1.Contains(x.Id1) && ids2.Contains(x.Id2))
                  .AnyAsync(x => ids.Contains(new { id1 = x.Id1, id2 = x.Id2 }));
```

This way, at least smaller bunch of records will be fetched.

Also you can think to another solution:

```
public async Task<bool> IfExist(IEnumerable<string> ids1, IEnumerable<string> ids2)
{
    var ids = ids1.Zip(ids2, (id1, id2) => $"{id1}***{id2}");
    return await DbSet.AnyAsync(x => ids.Contains(x.id1 + "***" + x.id2));
}
```

Comment: that string concats looks pretty intresting, i will check it out in the future, thanks!